# Working code crashing after made into an EXE by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, cx-freeze, py2exe

I have minimal knowledge on this subject, which is why I'm seeking help. I tried pyinstaller, CX freeze, and py2exe. None of them were able to convert my game into an exe. Pyinstaller came the closest. It was able to create a file, but it gave a fatal error as soon as it was opened.

Apparently opening it from the cmd would display error messages, if that was the cause. I did this but nothing showed up. I opened the unchanged code in Pycharm and it worked like a charm. No errors. Maybe it could be something wrong with the media directories, but I made sure the exe file was right next to the code that I tested.

This is the second time using pyinstaller, because it worked perfectly the first time. Pyinstaller can sometimes fail when others will work, but CX freeze and py2exe are pretty intimidating, because they kept giving cryptic errors. Please, I'm striking out here, if someone could find out what the problem is that would be fantastic.

Project available for download here: https://gofile.io/d/awjV5x

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created exe and it's working fine.

Create executable using the following command

```
pyinstaller --onefile code.py
```

Exe will be created in the dist folder and copy that back to the Last Stand Zombies Folder and double click the exe and the game will run straight away

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you tell me exactly how you did it? I included the -w command before, but now without it, it still doesn't work. The console pops up but not the game. The very first time it opened I caught a glimpse of a missing module message but now it's gone. Also, can you make your exe available for download? Gofile.io is pretty good.

Comment: Scratch that, I figured out what the missing module was. Turns out I didn't have pygame installed on the computer that I was making the exe with. I transferred my work using a usb because I didn't have admin access to add exclusions. But now I have a whole new problem, which is that the coordinates are completely messed up. This breaks the game, any ideas?

Comment: I should think before I type, because 10 minutes later, I've come to realize that it's probably because different computers have different screen sizes. Thanks anyway for your help.